# Unable to use JAXB by deployment of an application build with eclipse RCP

Tags: xml, jaxb, eclipse-rcp

currently I have build an application using eclipse RCP.
The application can create multiple products, save them in an XML file, and the file is loaded inside the application and displayed inside a table.
I have used JAXB to marshall and unmarshall the XML-file.

the current problem occurs when I want to deploy or export the application.
After explorting the application in the log file I get this error:

[rcp application with XML-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFC1A.png)

> [Command-Thread]1:CMD_TABLE_CHANGE_PRODUCT_DATA -> command thread started
>   CMD_TABLE_CHANGE_PRODUCT_DATA loading products data
>   Loading data from XML file: C:/temp/myCompanyProductSuite/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/2/0/.cp/appdata/products.xml
>   Exception: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of com.myCompany.app.model.objects.Product
>    - with linked exception:
>   [java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:740)
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:262)
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:705)
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:186)
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:576)
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:555)
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:168)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
>   com.myCompany.server.ProductServer.loadProductsFromXMLFile(ProductServer.java:188)
>   com.myCompany.server.ProductServer.loadProductData(ProductServer.java:106)
>   com.myCompany.server.ProductServer.loadProductServerData(ProductServer.java:68)
>   com.myCompany.server.ProductServer.getApplicationProducts(ProductServer.java:83)
>   com.myCompany.app.gui.parts.model.ProductViewerModel.getApplicationProducts(ProductViewerModel.java:65)
>   com.myCompany.app.gui.parts.ProductViewerPart$ProductViewerPartController.handleControlledCommand(ProductViewerPart.java:261)
>   com.myCompany.app.mvc.MVCController$1.run(MVCController.java:106)
>   Loading data from XML file: unmarshalling ended

I did not really find a helpul answer on the internet.

I can only assure you that I have included the 3 JAR files (jaxb-api, jaxb-core, jaxb-impl) of JAXB for the deployment inside the manifest of the plugin.

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 properties/,
 appdata/,
 lib/log4j.jar,
 lib/jaxb-2.2.11/jaxb-api.jar,
 lib/jaxb-2.2.11/jaxb-impl.jar,
 lib/jaxb-2.2.11/jaxb-core.jar,
 lib/jaxb-2.2.11/jaxb-xjc.jar
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

Can you please advice me what I can do to solve the problem.

Best Regards,
Kais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also using JAXB in one of my app (JMSToolBox) and I didn't do anything specific for the application (one product + multiple plugins) to work.
I didn't add extra libraries to neither the plugin or product or manifest as you did.
JMSToolBox runs on JDK 7 with eclipse v4.5.2 and JAXB classes (ie javax.xml.bind.* classes) are included within the JRE that I bundle (the JRE) with the application, specifically Oracle/Sun JRE v1.7.0.80
Does your application runs well inside eclipse, ie when started from the eclipse worbench or do you have this problem only when you build/export the application?

Comment: Hello titou10,
thanks for responding.

My XML-File is loaded in the application when I run the application inside
eclipse-rcp.
However, if I export it, the XML-File is not loaded, because a JAXb-exception
occurs. I don't really know why?
I'm using JDK7.
I the only thing that I do, is that I'm using a thread where inside I unmarshall
the XML file.

I hope this can help you understand my problem.

Comment: What I can says for sure is that you don't need to include/define the JAXB ri jars (jaxb-api.jar etc.)  in your app as they are included in the JRE. It seems your problem is related to a classpath problem or the way you create the thread that unmarshall the file Q: are you using the same JRE inside eclipse and outside? maybe you don't "export" all the dependencies that are used inise eclipse

Comment: Hi titou10, thanks for responding, I have created a new RCP-Project and migrated my package there. I was able to understand the problem. I have used static variables inside a class which are called from the Product-Class, the problem that inside the Product-Class occurs an exception. This is why the unmarshalling is not succeeded. Now I have exported the application -> I got :) the data but still have some exceptions. So, I will just avoid to use some complicated codes inside the classes that I want to unmarshall.

Comment: :) By the way it works without the JAXB-Library... O:) I also got some problems with using eclipse-rcp-64-bit and a JDK7-32bit. Anyway, I have now the brand new eclipse-mars2-32bit and the JDK-7-32bit. I can say :D I got all problems that one can get. Thanks for your time.